# Modulo arithmetic not optimized out by gcc?

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, assembly, modulo

Consider this simple function which adds a constant:

```c
unsigned char f(unsigned char x) {
    return x + 5;
}
```

This generates the following assembly (with `-O3` on gcc 4.7.2):

```asm
leal    5(%rdi), %eax
ret
```

Now since unsigned overflow is well-defined behavior in C, one would assume that adding a modulo operation should be essentially a nop:

```c
unsigned char f(unsigned char x) {
    return (x + 5) % 256; // assume char is 8-bits, which is typical
}
```

But the assembly generated has an extra instruction:

```asm
leal    5(%rdi), %eax
movzbl  %al, %eax
ret
```

Can someone enlighten me why this is so?  I'm not very familiar with assembly though.

(Note: This is just a toy problem that I made to understand how GCC optimizes code.)

Comment: ICC does it too, Clang has the `movzbl` in either case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a definite answer to 'why the generated code is different', you probably need an engineer with intimate knowledge of the details of this `gcc` compiler. You may want to experiment more with a couple more examples as below:

```
unsigned char f1(unsigned char x) { return x + 5; }
unsigned char f2(unsigned char x) { return (x + 5) % 256; }
unsigned char f3(unsigned char x) { return (x + 5) % 256U; }
unsigned char f4(unsigned char x) { return (x + 5) & 0xFFU; }
```

With `gcc` version 4.1.2 suitable for 64 bit systems, I get the same code for all these functions both for 64 bit as 32 bit code. Which actually all include the `movzbl`. Which might be a bug in `gcc` compiling `f1` (and likely corrected at the caller side). It really depends on the calling conventions: whether an 8 bit value in a 64 bit register should be zero/sign extended or not. I couldn't find a conclusive answer to this in the Draft Version 0.96 of the *System V Application Binary Interface, AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement* of June 14, 2005. The `gcc` compiler 4.1.2 seems to adopt the philosophy of 'better safe than sorry' as the `movzbl` also occurs on the caller side. In my experience one normally requires such values to be zero/sign extended unless one has operations operating on parts of a register, which is quite unusual.

Interestingly my home compiler `gcc` version 4.3.2 does make a small difference in that `f2` is implemented through an *and* operation. All the others just add 5, strongly suggesting that it is the callers responsibility to perform zero/sign extension, which it indeed does. But this is 32 bit code.

If I find a conclusive answer on the zero/sign extension of values in oversized registers in any of the architecture specifications, then I'll let you know. I happen to need to know this professionally too.

In defense of your `gcc` compiler. You are looking at *small beer optimizations*. Normal code does not contain such a modulo and it is nice if the compiler somewhere down the line will reduce such a special modulo to an *and*. In case of the `%256` (vs `%256U`) some value range analysis is required to determine that an *and* suffices, because the modulo is done in 'signed' arithmetic. Clearly my compiler does conclude at some point that the *and* suffices, but apparently too late to determine that it then is subsumed by the typing of the result, which it did determine in the other cases. This is what we compiler engineers call the 'phase ordering problem'.

**Update on zero/sign extension of values in registers.**

I've abandoned the quest for now and will have to continue with some colleagues as I've not found a conclusive statement if parameters/functions results are expected to be zero/sign extended.

I did find the following relating to this in the above mentioned ABI specification.

> Booleans, when stored in a memory object, are stored as single byte objects the value of which is always 0 (false) or 1 (true). When stored in integer registers or passed as arguments on the stack, all 8 bytes of the register are significant; any nonzero value is considered true.

So boolean types have to be zero extended.

> For calls that may call functions that use varargs or stdargs (prototype-less calls or calls to functions containing ellipsis (. . . ) in the declaration) `%al` (Note 14) is used as hidden argument to specify the number of SSE registers used. The contents of `%al` do not need to match exactly the number of registers, but must be an upper bound on the number of SSE registers used and is in the range 0–8 inclusive.
>
> Note 14: Note that the rest of `%rax` is undefined, only the contents of `%al` is defined.

So for this special use of `%al` it need not be extended.

Considering that booleans have to be zero extended one may conclude that the spirit of the ABI is that other sub-word types should also be extended. Taking a more formal stance one can argue that the absence of any statement should be interpreted as no zero/sign extension is required. All in all, not satisfactory.

**Update 2 on zero/sign extension of values in registers.**

I've discussed the issue with a colleague. The newest version of the ABI from 2012 version 0.99 has been changed exactly on the parameter passing of booleans in that these are only zero extended to 8 bits. That suggest that this has been modified to be in line with passing other sub-word types as all being **not** zero/sign extended. The AMD64 architecture also supports sub-word registers for half of the 64 bit registers and can do operations on these sub-word registers. That is probably the motivation not to pass parameters in a zero/sign extended fashion.

Comment: It's worthwhile to note that C11 no longer allows `intvar = intval % 256;` to be optimized using a simple "AND" instruction but instead requires that compilers favor the almost-never-useful identity `(-n) % 256 == -(n % 256)` rather than `(n+256) % 256 == n % 256`.  If one wants optimized behavior, one must cast to unsigned first.

Comment: @Bryan: Since my post got downvoted, I've taken it down - so you may want to edit your post in reflection to that... I thought my answer was pretty decent, but as there wasn't a comment to say why, I don't know what was wrong with it.

Comment: @supercat Probably due to a lack of mathematical education in computer science. As far as I know this has however been standing practice for a long time in C.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Will do. A totally unjust downvote if you'd ask me.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Not sure what happened there but I thought it was pretty useful and gave some food for thought.

Comment: @BryanOlivier: I'm not sure "math education" has anything to do with it.  I've encountered many situations where I've used division or modulus operations on things that should have a repeating pattern, and had to add special-case code to prevent odd behavior when things cross zero.  Behavior which favors either identity could be justified *mathematically*, but from a pragmatic standpoint, applications where periodic behavior is useful would seem to outnumber those where round-to-zero is helpful.

Comment: Ah well, it's rather unfortunate that compilers are not very consistent about this and that there isn't a clear answer from the ABI specification either.

Comment: @supercat It was **never allowed** to compile a signed `intval % 256` expression into a simple “logical and” unless the compiler a) wanted to make all integer divisions round towards -infinity despite the hardware always provide round-towards-zero or b) was able to determine the sign of `intval`. Before C99, it used to be **implementation-defined** whether division rounded towards 0 or -infinity. The remainder `%` is defined from division though Euclid's equation. A compiler could not willy-nilly compile some divisions (or remainders) according to one convention and others according to another

Comment: @supercat You are right that casting to unsigned is a good way to indicate to the compiler that you want it to optimize, tough. The same applies to a division by a power of two of a signed quantity that you know to be positive but do not expect the compiler to be able to infer so. Or you could just write the logical shift yourself while you're at it.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Having integers divide toward negative infinity would facilitate some types of code, and most processors' divide instructions are so horribly slow that cleanup code wouldn't affect things much.  Further, a lot of embedded devices have some hardware to facilitate unsigned division, but not necessarily signed division.

Comment: I have looked at code for "% 2^n" in GCC recently, and if the input is signed, it will add extra code to deal with sign extension of the result, but it will use an "and" operation to perform the actual "dividie/modulo". Which is one reason I suggest that if you KNOW you want/is happy with the "and-effect", you write "X & (2^n-1)" instead of "X % 2^n" when signed values are involved (e.g. making simple "if it's an even 16 do something special")

Comment: @fzlogic I've added the conclusion me and a colleague have drawn from the newest ABI version (see Update 2).